# Fire base return generated values to calling app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build a Firebase cloud function that generates an instrument part for the user. The cloud function should be called from the app generate the part and then return the generated part to the app for recording.

Here is my App function:

```
    public void addInstrumentToMix() {
         //Allow the user to select an instrument

         //once the user has seleced there instrument generate that instruments part

        //call firebase cloud function to generate instrument part and return to it to app
    }
```

Here is my cloud function:

```
  exports.generateGuitarPart = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      //Use math to generate notes per instrument, eventually would like to generate these instrument peices through machine learning

      var notes = {"21","45"} //sample value

  return notes;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a response to the client from your function.  Returning a value from the function doesn't actually send anything back.  A minimal function that sends a response back to the client was in your index.js that the Firebase CLI made for you when you ran `firebase init`.

```
exports.generateGuitarPart = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  //Use math to generate notes per instrument, eventually would like to generate these instrument peices through machine learning
    response.send({"21","45"})
})
```

Please [consult the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to better understand how HTTPS type functions work.